# Sending props or changing state fo the child won't refresh the Render in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React, so if someone can please enlighten me. I have a **component parent and a component child**. I do some data fetching on father, and then I pass the new result through props to the child. But the child is not updating on the render. {the number remains the same} I know its working because I used console.log both in the parent and in the child, and the value is perfect, only the render doesn't show it.

The parent component add props "qtd" to the child:

```
{this.state.products.map((item)=><div> <Card key={item.id} id={item.id} qtd={item.qtd} title={item.title} addCardCount={this.addCardCount} subtractCardCount={this.subtractCardCount} ref={instance => { this.card = instance; }} /></div> )}
```

Then, when I add this to the child:

```
{ this.props.qtd }
```

Nothing happens on the view.

Even when I change child state through a parent, the view remains the same. Do you know a better way to do this? Do you know the possible causes for this to not work? Appreciate your help.

Comment: You need to show more complete code ([mcve]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as follow:

In your child component:

```
class Child from React.Component {

   componentDidUpdate(previousProps) {
       if (previousProps !== this.props) {
           this.forceUpdate()
       }
   }

   render() {
       return (<div>{this.props.qtd}</div>)
   }

}
```

You could also use setState() instead for forceUpdate(), and make a conditional render with your state value.

Comment: React obviously re-renders the component automatically when it receives new props. That's the entire point of React.

Comment: @JJJ you're absolutely right, re-editing the answer. Just had a mistake as I was having a similar problem today but was because of my implementation and directly thought of that when I saw this.

Comment: I don't know if its the same, but using the function componentWillReceiveProps also solved the problem. I need to study more about those components functions. Thank you!

Comment: @GuilhermeNunes I posted using component disparate because componentWillReceiveProps is considered legacy code and should be avoid in new code (even though you can still use it) :)